# Including payment module in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment

I am working on an online shopping site in CI framework. I want to make payment online and currently want to support master card, Visa and PayPal. Since I am new to online payment and stuffs I have no idea what to do. Is there any library available for all these or should I do it for each one separately. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, It's called CI Merchant: ci-merchant.org

Answer (score 2):

it is easy to integrate paypal. look at the documentation @

https://developer.paypal.com/

if you need another type of payment gateway, the configurations may differ from the payment gateway you choosed.

All Payment gateway service providers provide a good documentation for integrating their service to your site...

Single Payment Gateway which support Credit Cards, Debit Cards, and NetBanking in one entity are available....
(Eg. CCavenue, EBS, billdesk etc..)

Comment: Just checked CCavenue. So if I want to add Paypal I should add it seperately. It won't come under CCavenue.. right ?

Comment: yea, paypal is somewhat independent